# after change windows and update android studio the project that I worked on it didn't run and show some errors

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'.

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:\Flutter\Flutter_Projects\news_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 58s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ullC.png)

Comment: `AccessDeniedException` means that you don't have rights to the folder.

Comment: @KenWhite the folder full control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone already had a similar issue in [Github](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1822). I think you can go to the link and follow the solution shown there. Let me know if it fixed the issue.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Le di en Clean Project

Build > Clean Project